# enforce local version of shared dependency to be used by webpack module federation

Tags: webpack, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

During the local development of my app, I see that one of the remote entries got executed quicker than the local app code and it sets the production version of React to be used, while I always want to have the development one from my node_modules when I develop locally.

Is there a way to enforce the local version to be used no matter what remotes config says?

In my particular case, both remote and local have React: 18.2.0 version (latest), so as the remote brings the latest version of the shared singleton dependency first, the local one is not used.

AFAIR I can change the remote config of shared dependency to specify a lower version of react, e.g.

```
    react: {
      requiredVersion: false,
      singleton: true,
      version: '18.0.0',
    }
```

so if the remote has a lower version, my local 18.2.0 one will override it and I'll get the dev version locally. But is there a way to enforce this behaviour just from the local configuration without touching the remote config?

UPD: it seems like it is possible to just specify a fake higher version in your own config. E.g. if the remote gives you 18.2.0 which is the same version as in your own local app, you can put a fake higher version of the shared dependency and it'll be preferred by the plugin.